# Binding an event handler to any type of event using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, events

I have some code where I need to dynamically bind events to an event handler:

```
foreach (string evnt in attribute.Events)
{
    EventInfo ei = control.GetType().GetEvent(evnt);
    if(ei != null)
    {
        ei.AddEventHandler(control, new EventHandler((s, e) =>
        {
            // More awesomeness here...
        }));
    }
}
```

So for each string in the event list, get the event from the control and bind a handler.

The problem is that not all events are `EventHandler`, some for example might be `KeyEventHander` or `MouseEventHandler` etc.

I don't want a massive if/else list of `EventHandler` derived types, I just want to bind the same handler regardless of what type of `EventHandler` it is.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is wrong with what you currently have?

Comment: @YacoubMassad - exception...Object of type 'System.EventHandler' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler'.

Comment: @YacoubMassad basically I need the expression (s, e) => {...} to apply to any EventHander derived type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

First create this helper class:

```
public class HandlerHelper<T> where T : EventArgs
{
    private readonly EventHandler m_HandlerToCall;

    public HandlerHelper(EventHandler handler_to_call)
    {
        m_HandlerToCall = handler_to_call;
    }

    public void Handle(object sender, T args)
    {
        m_HandlerToCall.Invoke(sender, args);
    }
}
```

This generic class has a `Handle` method that will be used to be our delegate for the many event handler types. Note that this class is generic. `T` will be one of the many `EventArgs` derived classes for different event types.

Now let's say you define the following event handler:

```
var event_handler = new EventHandler((s, args) =>
{
    // More awesomeness here...
});
```

Here is how you can use the helper class to create different delegates for the different event handler types that will invoke `event_handler`:

```
foreach (var event_name in event_names)
{
    var event_info = control.GetType().GetEvent(event_name);

    var event_handler_type = event_info.EventHandlerType;

    var event_args_type = event_handler_type.GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters()[1].ParameterType;

    var helper_type = typeof(HandlerHelper<>).MakeGenericType(event_args_type);

    var helper = Activator.CreateInstance(helper_type, event_handler);

    Delegate my_delegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(event_handler_type, helper, "Handle");

    event_info.AddEventHandler(button, my_delegate);
}
```

For each event, we obtain the `EventHandlerType` which is like `EventHandler` or `MouseEventHandler`.

Then we use reflection to get the type of the second parameter which is like `EventArgs` or `MouseEventArgs`.

Then we create an instance of `HandlerHelper<>` based on the type of the `EventArgs` parameter. For example `HandlerHelper<EventArgs>` or `HandlerHelper<MouseEventArgs>`.

We give `event_handler` to the constructor of `HandlerHelper` so that it can call it when it's `Handle` method is invoked.

This makes the signature of the `Handle` method as we want. For example, in the case of `HandlerHelper<MouseEventArgs>`, the signature of the `Handle` method is:

```
void Handle(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
```

Now, we use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to create a delegate based on the `Handle` method for the specific `HandlerHelper` object that we created, and we give such delegate to the `AddEventHandler` method.

For performance reasons, you can cache the delegate (instead of creating one every time) based on `event_args_type`.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcGravell

Comment: I get an error with this: Type helper = typeof(HandleHelper<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(MouseEventArgs));        The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition.

Comment: Very strange. I tested this code before posting. Did you copy the `HandleHelper` as is? It has a single generic parameter, and we are passing a single type to `MakeGenericType`.

Comment: It is very strange. I copied the HandleHelper class into a console application and tested with Type t = typeof(HandleHelper<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(EventArgs));.....worked just fine - then in my other solution it just dies!

Comment: ...for some reason it doesn't like HandleHelper<T> being a nested class! :-S that may be where I was going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic key word to attach the handler. More explanation you can find here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not in this case, you can't; not when the event name is a `string` (see `evnt` in the question). The `dynamic` keyword will do *nothing* to help here. The article you link to has **nothing at all** to do with the "dynamic key word"